# How to validate a url address in jquery using Regex?

Tags: jquery, regex

I have searched a lot but didn't get the answer.
How to validate URLs like `www.google.com` and `http://www.google.com`
using regular expressions? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by validate an URL? Check if it starts with "http://", or "www": `^(?:http|www)`. Have you tried anything?

Comment: it could be starting from  both "www" or "http://"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function to test valid url as:

```
function validateUrl()   // return true or false.
{
    var urlregex = new RegExp(
          "^(http:\/\/www.|https:\/\/www.|ftp:\/\/www.|www.){1}([0-9A-Za-z]+\.)");
    return urlregex.test(textval);
}
```

Comment: your solution not working at all. see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KJW4E/1284/

Comment: jsfiddle.net/KJW4E/1286 this also not working... returning false

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this one, that does not depend on the string start/end:

```
(\b((?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)([0-9A-Za-z]+\.?)+\b)
```

See [example here](https://regex101.com/r/cF9gX2/2).